# Need html checkbox label to wrap "nicely"

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a grid of checkboxes where each cell has a fixed width, and each checkbox is preceded with a small image.  In cases where the label text is too long, I'm having a hard time getting the text to wrap underneath the checkbox.

[image: screenshot 1]

Referring to the above screenshot, I'd like "text that wraps" to be aligned with the checkbox, rather than wrapping underneath the image, like so:

[image: screenshot 2]

I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s8Db/3/) with my current markup and styles. What I can't change is the HTML structure, but any CSS changes are fine.

Here is a code snippet:

```css
.checkbox-list {
}
img.placeholder{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
td {
    padding:2px;
    width:150px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
label {
    /*display:inline-block;*/
}
```

```html
<table class="checkbox-list">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <img class="placeholder"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Some really long text that wraps</span></label></td>
        <td>
            <img class="placeholder"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Foo</span></label></td>
        <td>
            <img class="placeholder"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Foo</span></label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
            <img class="placeholder"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Foo</span></label></td>
        <td>
            <img class="placeholder"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Foo</span></label></td>
        <td>
            <img class="placeholder"/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <span>Foo</span></label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Hmmm...I don't see the lightblue boxes.

Comment: @AllenLiu what browser are you using?  i tested on chrome and IE.

Comment: I'm using on FF v7 on Windows 7.  I simply added a 'float:left;' to `img.placeholder` and I can now see the boxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just apply a `margin-bottom` to the image and `float: left`:

```
img.placeholder{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    float: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9s8Db/5/).

---

**Edited** because I am, apparently, an *idiot*, and didn't realise the simplest approach was to assign the `display: block;` and `margin-left: 18px;` to the `label` element, and float the `.placeholder` elements:

```
img.placeholder{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    float: left;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9s8Db/10/).

Floating the image prevents the `label` from starting on a new-line, the margin-left on the `label` is the width of the image and a small 2px 'gutter' to visually separate the image and the checkbox (adjust to taste, obviously).

Comment: this is close, but what happens when the text spans more than 2 or 3 lines?  it will eventually begin to wrap underneath the image again.  it also adds a margin below the second row of checkboxes, where none of the labels wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

make `img`, `input`, and `span` into block elements and `float: left`;

http://jsfiddle.net/9s8Db/4/

Answer (score 0):

specifying label with `display:inline-block` and giving it a width seems to do the trick.  though ideally i wouldn't have to specify the label width.

http://jsfiddle.net/9s8Db/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you constrain the `width` of the `label` and float `img.placeholder` and `label`, it should work as you requested:

http://jsfiddle.net/9s8Db/8/

```
img.placeholder{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    float: left;
}
td {
    padding:2px;
    width:150px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
label {
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: thanks.  similar to my solution, though i managed without having to float any elements